# Lyx: header/footer stopped working {scrpage2}

Tags: lyx, scrpage2

I posted this in another thread and was told to open a new one. Here we go:

How do I add header and footer in Lyx 2.2.2

I had this preamble and it worked.

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{4776020 Stephan Goldenberg}
\ohead{01801 WS 2016/2017 EA 3}
\ifoot{\today}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
```

But there was an update for Lyx which obviously broke it. How do I get header and footer back ?

Edit: I don't know Latex, though. Noobish words please :)

Edit2: So I did what the user guide says but still no header & footer. I've deleted the preamble and the errors went away but still no header & footer.

[image]

I don't get it to work, Lyx seems broken.

I've started a new blank document. Page style is set to fancy, custom header/footerlines is added in the modules section, preamble is empty. But still no header and no footer. Obviously I'm too numb for this, I give up.

[image]

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\lhead{4776020 Stephan Goldenberg}

\rhead{01801 WS 2016/2017 EA 3}

\lfoot{\textbackslash{}today}

\rfoot{\textbackslash{}pagemark}

Aufgabe 3.1:
...

\_10010101
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at Help > User Guide at Section "6.11 Customized Page Headers and Footers"

Comment: Thanks for answering but that did not help. I did what the user guide said and now I'm getting errors and the page number at the bottom has disappeared too.  

LaTeX Error: Command \chead already defined.
LaTeX Error: Command \cfoot already defined.

These are not defined by me. Like I said, this is not for mere mortals. I had to turn in, thank god, I could produce something using LibreOffice.

Comment: Maybe LyX already loads either `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage`. In this case you cannot use `scrpage2` and you don't need to use it. Simply use the package LyX already loads. BTW: `scrpage2` is obsolete. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Schweinebacke ist schön :)

Forgot to mention that I've removed my preamble before this but still no worky.

Comment: Strange, if I do exactly what you say at the end there it works fine here. No errors or warnings? Can you open the Source pane (View->Source Pane), choose *Complete source* in the drop-down menu on the right (probably says *Current paragraph* by default), and copy-paste everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` into your question?

Comment: Ah, good idea. I've added the source to the question and removed most of the math stuff. I don't get any errors or warnings. I do get a page number centered at the bottom. I think the full log is too long, so I made a gist: https://gist.github.com/stehgold/9522b036a1c624f50295613021a96c91

Thanks,

Stephan

Comment: Ah, you're using the `amsart` class. I was using the standard `article`, where it works fine. Is `amsart` a requirement?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly me using this. As I said, I don't know Latex. That's why I use Lyx. I've chosen AMS Article because I think, I need this for math. This used to work, but there was an update which broke it. I've just fiddled with the facncyheader stuff like the user guide suggests.

Comment: Ah, I've changed this to article and I get header and footer.

Comment: But it's still flawed. There is a pagenum centered at the bottom which is not from me. And no date, there's {\today} and {\thepage} printed...

I did it using Texstudio now, worked fine.

Thank you,
Stephan

Comment: If you just type a backslash in LyX, LyX assumes that you actually want to print a backslash in the document. In order to use (La)TeX code, you need to placeit  in a "TeX Code" inset, found under Insert --> TeX code (shortcut Ctrl +L). Place `\today` and `\thepage` in such a inset and it will work. To remove the pagenumber in the bottom center, I suppose you can just add the corresponding footer field, and keep it empty.

Comment: Also, one thing I forgot to say about this site: You as the owner of a post will always be notified of comments. But if you want to make sure other users are notified, you need to write `@<username>` in the comment. Tab-completion is available, so if you write e.g. `@Torb` you should see a small box with my username appear, and you can then hit the Tab-key to complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that cause your problems here:

1. It seems that the `amsart` class, that you were using, sets a different page style for the first page only. I'm sure if you add some text on the second page, you'll see the header and footer appear.

   To make the first page have the `fancy` pagestyle as well, place the cursor at the start of the document, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and type `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in the box that appears.

   In the standard `article` class this is not necessary.
2. If you type `\today` directly in LyX, LyX assumes that you actually want to display a backslash followed by `today` in the PDF, so it inserts `\textbackslash{}today`. To use LaTeX code in the document, you need to add a TeX Code inset, as mentioned above, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or insert -> TeX Code).
3. If the header and footer of the `fancy` pagestyle is not cleared, the default settings are kept, and they include a pagenumber in the center field of the footer. To remove that, add the *Center footer* in the same way as the right and left footer, and keep it empty.

Here is an example `.lyx` file which uses `amsart`, but with the custom header and footer on all pages:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass amsart
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
eqs-within-sections
figs-within-sections
customHeadersFooters
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Left Header
4776020 Stephan Goldenberg
\end_layout

\begin_layout Right Header
01801 WS 2016/2017 EA 3
\end_layout

\begin_layout Left Footer
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
today
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Right Footer
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thepage
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Center Footer

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{fancy}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Some text
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Next page
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

And a screenshot of the LyX GUI and output:

[image]